# MongoDB 3.6.2 2008R2 Plus Not Installing

Tags: mongodb, installation, failed-installation

I'm trying to install MongoDb 3.6.2 2008R2 plus on my 64bit Window 10 (build no 1709) but the setup after some time says "setup wizard ended prematurely because of an error.your system has not been modified.To. Install this program at a later time run setup wizard again.click finish button to exit the setup." Any one know any fix regarding this issue?

Comment: Did you found solution? Have the same problem

Comment: None of the answers worked for me. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: I don't have Compass installed and also have the same installation problem

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I solved this problem by declining to install Compass together with Mongo in the installer wizard.

Comment: Yes, this work. You need to decline to install mongodb compass. Then, you install it again, change the installation and install mongodb compass.

Comment: This fixes mongo's premature ending.

Comment: For me it worked only like this: decline compass and run the installer. Then download a separate compass installer from the https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?#compass (windows!)

Answer (score 37):

I have the same issue. I solved it by choosing the following way:-

1. Choose Custom Installation
2. Uncheck Compass Installation with MongoDb
3. Finish the Setup
4. Again start setup and click on change the installation
5. Tick Compass Installation with MongoDb
6. Finish the Setup

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solved it by removing these folders that created on previous setup and running the setup again:

1. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MongoDB Compass Community
2. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MongoDB Inc
3. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompassCommunity

and some files like this in Prefetch folder:

C:\Windows\Prefetch\MONGODBCOMPASSCOMMUNITY.EXE-0044164A.pf

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggestion above but none works for me. Instead, I ended up downloading the archive version and extract that and place that in the folder structure below (on Windows 10, 64 bit)
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6.5\

Then I configured the system environment path and it works fine. As this is for testing, it would be fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

I unselected ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" in the Windows Features (Turn Windows features on or off). After restarting mongodb and Compass got installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install MongoDB Enterprise 2008R2 for Windows 10 64-bit and had the exact same problem.
I already had Compass installed, so here is what I did:

1. Uninstall Compass
2. Select install when needed (this will get you to the next page where you're prompted to install Compass or not. If you choose Install Everything you WON'T get the option to NOT install Compass (the other comments here might be earlier versions of Mongo... I'm not sure).
3. Install
4. Now re-install Compass.

That fixed it for me.