# Installing MongoDB compass this may take a few minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It has been half an hour and it is still stuck at the same progress. My machine is Windows 7 and I have downloaded the Community Server 2008 R2 64-bit and later. [Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbfZk.png)

Does anyone know why? Do I really need Compass if I were to use it with Node.js?
I'm new to MongoDB and node.js
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need it? Well no, which is why it was an "option" in the installer that you could have "un-ticked". Your screenshot is not going to tell anyone much ( as screenshots rarely do ) and there are plenty of posts around (  probably mostly on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) ) which would talk about viewing the logs and/or adding options to the `*.msi` to keep the logging information. You should probably look to see that another dialog has not popped up asking for "permission" to do something though. But cancelling this install won't cause any issues.

Comment: Various experiences here - [MongoDB 3.6.2 2008R2 Plus Not Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474477/mongodb-3-6-2-2008r2-plus-not-installing) As generally noted, the Compass option can be deselected and if you really want to install it, then you can do so as a standalone install. All the server installer package is doing is fetching the Compass package and running it's installer anyway.

Comment: Also I found this https://checkinnuggets.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/installation-update-of-mongodb-3-6-2-on-windows-hangs/

Comment: This is 2021 AND the same problem is STILL prevalent with version 4.4.5!

Answer (score 12):

As for January 2021, I've faced this issue with version 4.4.3. Press cancel on the installation won't help, and need to close the PowerShell process.

Then, Re-install without the compass, and after successful installation, install manually only the compass itself.

Answer (score 10):

Compass is a GUI client which can be used to manages collections, documents etc.

To do development in Node.JS (or any other programming language) **you do not need Compass** as it is a GUI tool which is a mongo client.

You can use **mongo CLI client**(Recommended). If you really need GUI tool, you can try [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/).

Only MongoDB server + any client is needed for most web development. Any client can be used to configure it, like CLI or Robo 3T or compass.

Although, you even don't need local installation of mongoDB server. You can use a cloud database like [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). It has all tools inbuilt as is very powerful. However I would still recommend doing a local installation of mongo server to avoid dependency of network while testing your app.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading/installing version 4.0.14 worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following link.
https://checkinnuggets.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/installation-update-of-mongodb-3-6-2-on-windows-hangs/

Instead of choosing Complete Installation, choose "Custom" instead, then at the last step, uncheck 'Install MongoDB Compass'. This will complete the installation.

Comment: Please use links only as a reference.