# Why MongoDB folder is not generated inside programs files after successfully installation at windows 10?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB inside my machine as a local , after install the installation exe of MongoDB but MongoDB folder did not generated even checked inside programs files and x86 also in both.
Please help me out what should i try to install it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

See [MongoDB 3.6.2 2008R2 Plus Not Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474477/mongodb-3-6-2-2008r2-plus-not-installing) - basically during install you need to uncheck the "Install compass" option for some reason. Not sure why, but installing without Compass works.